# @Autowired dependency with custom scope remains null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, tomcat7

I set up a custom spring scope in a web application.
The scope handles creation, map-based storage and distribution of datasource-based NamedParameterJdbcTemplate objects.

I have a baffling problem with this setup: it works fine on one computer, and not on the other. Both have Tomcat 7.0.52, one has Oracle Java, the other OpenJDK. One is Mac, the other Linux.

The relevant setup in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSourceScope" class="com.example.backoffice.controller.springconfig.DataSourceScope"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="dataSourceScope">
                <ref bean="dataSourceScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="engineDataSource" class="javax.sql.DataSource" scope="dataSourceScope">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="engineDatabase" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" scope="dataSourceScope">
    <constructor-arg ref="engineDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="configService" class="com.example.core.config.service.ConfigService" scope="dataSourceScope">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

The DataSourceScope code is (excerpted to the bare essentials):

```
public class DataSourceScope implements Scope {

private volatile Map<String, DataSource> datasources = new HashMap<String, DataSource>();
private volatile Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> templates = new HashMap<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate>();
private volatile Map<String, ConfigService> services = new HashMap<String, ConfigService>();

public void setDatasources(Map<String, DataSource> sources) {
    Map<String, ConfigService> services = new HashMap<String, ConfigService>();
    for (Entry<String, DataSource> entry : sources.entrySet()) {
        datasources.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate t = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(entry.getValue());
        templates.put(entry.getKey(),t);
        services.put(entry.getKey(), new ConfigService(t));
    }
    this.services = services;
}

@Override
public Object get(String name, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
    if (name.indexOf("configService") > -1) {
        return this.services.get(databaseName);
    } else if (name.indexOf("engineDatabase") > -1) {
        return this.templates.get(databaseName);
    } else if (name.indexOf("engineDataSource") > -1){
        return this.datasources.get(databaseName);
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException("DataSourceScope is not configured to wire beans with name " + name);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in those places where I wire 'engineDatabase', the object remains null. No warnings or exceptions with org.springframework logging at debug, until I try to use the database in one of the classes where it should be wired up (-> NPE).

Things seem related to the fact that NamedParameterJdbcTemplate has no default constructor. Still, I declare it with its required argument in applicationContext.xml. And even more telling, the setup works fine on one computer.

Comment: Have you debugged your `Scope` implementation? Does it get invoked?

Comment: I should have mentioned that: on the machine that is giving me the problem, I see it get invoked for the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate during application startup. At that point, I can also see that the map containing the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate objects contains the real instances that I expect to be there. However, when actually triggering the call that causes the NPE, the scope is not invoked.

Comment: Do you load your contexts in the same way on both machines? Do you have any version differences?

Comment: I thought about the thing some more, and realized that scoping the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate was not necessary, as the only thing that really should be scoped is the datasource it uses. So, I removed the scope element in its declaration, and things are now wired up correctly (at least on the one machine that wasn't having it previously). I'm hopeful, and it would stand to reason, that things will prove successful in all target environments.
Thanks for the help.